# Improving random selection: Python subnet mask generator

Tags: python, random, subnet

I created this code to generate random a random subnet mask (so I could practice converting them to their associated prefix, on paper). I am randomly creating a subnet mask ***one octet at a time***, but if any octet is NOT 255, the rest are automatically "0":

```
from random import randint

# choose subnet bytes at random
def pick_num():
    # list of valid subnet bytes
    list = [0, 128, 192, 224, 240, 248, 252, 254, 255]

    random = randint(0,8)
    num = list[random]
    return num

def generate_netmask():
    current_byte = 0
    submask_mask = ""
    count = 1
    while count <= 4:
        current_byte = pick_num()
        if current_byte == 255:
            submask_mask += str(current_byte) + "."
            count += 1
        else:
            submask_mask += str(current_byte) + "."
            count += 1
            break

    while count != 5:
        if count != 4:
            submask_mask += "0."
            count += 1
        elif count == 4:
            submask_mask += "0"
            count += 1

    return submask_mask

print(generate_netmask())
```

As a result, a majority of my output doesn't make it past the 1st or 2nd octet. For example: 128.0.0.0, 192.0.0.0, 254.0.0.0, etc. Every now and then I'll get something like: 255.255.192.0

I'm seeing this as a fun opportunity to learn about using randomness in code.

Can anyone recommend a way/ways of making this code more fair to the other subnet masks possibilities? I realize I could also make a list of all the subnet masks and randomly choose elements in the list.

Thank you in advance,
Sebastian

Comment: What is your definition of "fair"? Do you want `255` to appear more often? If you simply "make a list of all the subnet masks and randomly choose elements in the list," you will get similar results to what you have now.

Comment: Because my current code determines the octet numbers from LEFT to RIGHT and will turn all subsequent numbers to "0" if it detects a number lower than 255 (255 is one of 9 possibilities from the list), it will hardly ever get to the THIRD or FOURTH octet. I would like more diverse results.

Comment: I see several places in your code where you can reduce the amount you've written.
Instead of typing `submask_mask ... ` and incrementing the count twice, you can remove them from the `if` statements entirely, and only break when `current_byte` doesn't equal `255`. In you `while` loop you have another `if` statement, where you can remove the incrementing of the iterator from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a modified version of something I made to test a subnet mask validator:

**NOTE** - Tested using Python 2.7 in Rocky Linux 8.6 (Green Obsidian)

```
from random import randint

subnet_mask_list = []
prefix = 32
octets = (0, 128, 192, 224, 240, 248, 252, 254, 255,)
a = b = c = d = len(octets) - 1
# Create a list of dictionary items, consisting of a prefix (key) and mask (val),
# in descending order
while a > 0:
    # Add an item first...
    mask = '{0}.{1}.{2}.{3}'.format(octets[a], octets[b], octets[c], octets[d])
    subnet_mask_list.append({'prefix': prefix, 'mask': mask})
    # Then decrement the prefix and the subnet...
    prefix -= 1
    a -= 1 if b == 0 else 0
    b -= 1 if c == 0 and b > 0 else 0
    c -= 1 if d == 0 and c > 0 else 0
    d -= 1 if d > 0 else 0

# Iterate and query
for _ in range(100):
    r = randint(0, len(subnet_mask_list) - 1)
    try:
        p = input(
            'What is the prefix of {0} (Enter 0 to quit): '.format(
                subnet_mask_list[r]['mask']))
        if p == 0:
            print('Good-bye!')
            break
        elif p == subnet_mask_list[r]['prefix']:
            print('Good to go!')
        else:
            print('Nope.')
    except (NameError, SyntaxError):
        # Catch invalid entries here
        print('Nope.')
```

**Output:**

```
What is the prefix of 255.0.0.0 (Enter 0 to quit): 8
Good to go!
What is the prefix of 255.255.255.255 (Enter 0 to quit): 32
Good to go!
What is the prefix of 248.0.0.0 (Enter 0 to quit): 100
Nope.
What is the prefix of 255.255.248.0 (Enter 0 to quit): 21
Good to go!
What is the prefix of 255.224.0.0 (Enter 0 to quit): qwerty
Nope.
What is the prefix of 255.255.255.192 (Enter 0 to quit): 0
Good-bye!
```